# Probability with binomial distribution and random vectors

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

In a city the proportion of men with blue eyes is $20$%, of green eyes is $5$%, of black eyes is $10$% and the rest $65$% of men has brown eyes. Susan decides to commute from the center of the city to a small town. In order to get to the town, she has to take two buses which only take people from the city. She decides to run a little experiment which consists of drinking a beer with every man of blue or green eyes in each of the buses. Suppose every man accepts drinking a beer with her and that in the first bus there are $10$ men and in the second, $8$ men.

1)Calculate the probability that in the first part of the trip she has drunk less than $4$ beers.

2)Calculate the probability that she has drunk more than $3$ beers in total (in the two buses).

My attempt at a solution using user137481 hint:

1) If I call $X=\{\text{number of men in the first bus with blue eyes or green eyes}\}$, then $X \sim Bi(10,\dfrac{1}{4})$. I want to calculate the probability $$P(X <4)=\sum_{i=0}^3 {10 \choose i}(\dfrac{1}{4})^i(\dfrac{3}{4})^{10-i}$$

2) If I define $Y=\{\text{number of men in the second bus with blue eyes or green eyes}\}$, then $Y \sim Bi(8,\dfrac{1}{4})$, so $Z=X+Y \sim Bi(18,\dfrac{1}{4})$. The probability of Susan drinking more than 3 beers in total is $$P(Z >3)=1-P(Z \leq 3)$$$$=1-\sum_{i=0}^3 P(Z=i)$$$$=1-\sum_{i=0}^3{18 \choose i}(\dfrac{1}{4})^i(\dfrac{3}{4})^{10-i}$$

I would appreciate if someone could take a look at my solution and correct, if necessary, any mistakes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the first question, 25% (0.25) of the men have blue or green eyes and 75% of them do not. So, you just need to define a single random variable $X$ that is $Bin(10, 0.25)$. And then find $P(X < 4)$

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've edited my original post and I've solved the problem using your hint, could you take a look at it to see if I could follow the hint correctly?

Comment: Assuming independence, it shouldn't matter whether the men are in the first or second bus. For the second part, you can just use Bin(18, 0.25)